# Subquery returned more than 1 value error when using Update-Database in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration

I am using Entity Framework and trying to run a database migration from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. When I do, I get the following error and stack trace.

> PM> Update-Database -Verbose Using StartUp project 'Project'. Using
>   NuGet project 'DataModels'. Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the
>   SQL statements being applied to the target database. Target database
>   is: 'Database' (DataSource: Server, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient,
>   Origin: Configuration). Applying explicit migrations:
>   [201612061704158_MigrationName]. Applying explicit migration:
>   201612061704158_MigrationName. ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD
>   [ColumnName] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned
>   more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,
>   !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The
>   statement has been terminated.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations,
>   IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) ClientConnectionId:40e2fc22-5bbd-4d83-88f3-ce5b2bc378dc Error
>   Number:512,State:1,Class:16 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This
>   is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or
>   when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been
>   terminated.

I can't figure out what's going on here. Running the SQL statement directly works fine

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD [ColumnName] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

This is what the migration file looks like

```
public partial class MigrationName : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName");
    }
}
```

If I then comment out the contents of `Up()` in the migration file, I can successfully run the (empty) migration.

Also, if I run all the migrations, including this one, against an empty database, everything works fine. So there's some issue with the data that is causing the error (which is expected, given the error message).

I've tried looking at SQL Server Profiler to try to find out what SQL is being executed, but nothing is showing up.

I have about 20 other migrations that worked well up until this point, but this one and the previous one are consistently throwing this error.

Does anyone know what the underlying issue might be, or how I can get more information about what's going wrong?

Comment: Are there any triggers on `[TableName]`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Good question. There is, but if I drop it the migration fails in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My connection string had `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` set. Removing that from the connection string solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to write the migration yourself. I would do something like this

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.TablaName", "ColumnName");
    AddColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
}
```

OR

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
}
```

OR just add a column

```
 public override void Up()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.TablaName", "ColumnName");
    AddColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
}
```

I would leave the Down empty.

```
public override void Down(){}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Well, the column doesn't exist, which is why I'm trying to add it. Changing the migration to yours results in `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'ColumnName' does not exist in table 'TableName'.`

Comment: So if what are you trying to do is just a column then just use the `AddColumn("NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE", "NAME_OF_YOUR_COLUMN", c=>c.Boolean(nullable: false)` and leave Down empty

Comment: FYI, you need to replace ColumnName for the name of the column you are using.

Comment: That is exactly what I have in my question though.

Comment: Okay, How many migration files do you have? because if you have pending migration files it won't work. So, try to find if you have any pending migration besides the latest one

Comment: This is the only one that hasn't been applied.

Comment: Have you try to run Sql profiler and check the query EF is sending or is not event getting to that point.

Comment: I have captured the output in Profiler, and run all the queries that are logged there with no errors. It first does a few queries against the `[__MigrationHistory]` table, then runs the `ALTER TABLE` statement. But the statement doesn't actually get applied, and there is no query logged that produces the above error.

Comment: Can you post the connection string you are using for you code first?

Comment: `Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

Comment: Hey @KrisHarper At this point I'm trying to troubleshot with you So, when I do code first I use this connection string ''

Comment: Hey @KrisHarper At this point I'm trying to troubleshot with you So, when I do code first I use this connection string 
`server=testvalue;Database=testvalue; Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" `

Answer (score 0):

Changing the connection string also worked for me as Kris suggested, but I was concerned about how that would affect anything else using the same connection string.

What also worked for me was to empty out the `Up()` and `Down()` Methods, run the migration and roll back to the previous migration using `update-database -targetmigration:"PreviousMigrationName"`. Once this was done I could recreate the migration and run it without changing the connection string.